# ideas for uploading csv or xls in mvc to store in azure cloud table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage

Title pretty much says it all.. I want to upload an excel or csv file through my azure website mvc app, so that I can post it to my cloud table. Ideas?

Comment: This is pretty much just straightforward coding. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Use the code just like the Azure tutorial, dynamic create the table, and insert the fields into it.

Comment: my first attempt was an excel file (xls or xlsx) but this failed due to the strange vm-ish box hosting my web-site missing the required ACE or JET connectors required to read the files. I am trying csv now. I will update if I get stuck

Comment: If you want to actually manipulate the table entries within Azure Storage you'll want to use a table. Otherwise you may just want to upload the csv/xls into a blob. Depends on your scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

The AzCopy utility now supports importing / exporting data to / from Azure Tables. Take a look [AzCopy Getting Started](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#copy-entities-in-an-azure-table-with-azcopy-preview-version-only) for more information.